# Using realm how can i update data,It should not create new object only update object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Instead of saving data how to update the same object when we didSelectRowAt.

Like offerName "Diwali" to "oct" to without creating new object "diwali" should change to "oct".

How can i do that?

Program :-

```
let newArray = Discount()
 newArray.offerName = offerName.text!

               let percent = Float(offerValue.text!)
               newArray.segmentIndex = segment.selectedSegmentIndex
              newArray.percentage = percent!


                  //This will go to Create data and save
                   self.saveItems(category: newArray)

                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}    

func saveItems(category: Discount) {
           do{

               try realm.write {//Save/Create
                   realm.add(category)
               }               
           }catch {
               print("Error in saving \(error)")
           }
       }
```

Comment: realm.add(category, update: .all)

Comment: i need to add new function or where should i add this realm.add(category,update:.all)

Comment: I use realm.add(category,update:.all) ,but it is taking as new object not updating the existing object

Comment: please send me any reference program when i use didSelectRowAt screen will open and here i need to update the existing object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Examples below are written with a help of a [Realm swift documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

There are two ways to update objets in realm.

The first option is better for updating single object

```swift
var yourObject = Object()
    do {
      try realm.write {
        yourObject.property = "Some new value"
      }
    } catch {
      print("Unable to update object.")
    }
```

The second option is better for updating collection of objects:

```swift
    var arrayOfImageObjects = realm.objects(Image.self)
        
    do {
      try realm.write {
        // Update first item in array
        // Here we're updating isNewImage property and setting it to false
        arrayOfImageObjects.first!.setValue(false, forKeyPath: "isNewImage")
    
        // Update all images
        // Here we're updating isNewImage property of all images in array and setting it to false
        arrayOfImageObjects.setValue(false, forKeyPath: "isNewImage")
      }
    } catch {
      print("Unable to update objets.")
    }
```

Comment: Where should i add this arrayOfImageObjects.first!.setValue(false, forKeyPath: "isNewImage") . .       In my above program.  I need to give any condition for saving and updating or seperately i need to give.

Comment: There is no condition needed. You can just create function `updateItems()`, pass in parameters that you need to process and then in the function you can update items(with upper code chunk). Try to use your own logic, I can't really know what you want to achieve in your program. Please accept this answer if is correct.

Comment: I use this thing realm.add(category, update: .modified) to update.  It is updating data , but problem is it is not updating primary key object. if we update primary key object if it is new it is taking as new object, if already exist it is crashing.  How can i edit or update object without crashing?

Comment: Make sure you are making all data manipulation in realm.write closure.